# Is libvirt dnsmasq exposed to the network, if I run Fedora without a firewall?

Tags: fedora, security, firewall, dnsmasq, libvirt

There's this nice saying from Ubuntu: [no open ports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#ports) on the default install.  Other Linux OS's look similar, including Fedora.  Configuring firewall policies can be a pain in the neck, so this is a great default to have.

Ubuntu specifically exempt the DHCP client (essential) and mDNS.  (Without firewall zones to distinguish, mDNS is nice to leave enabled.  Poettering put some work into ensuring avahi-daemon is safe and secure, I think specifically for this reason).

So I can turn off Fedora's `firewalld`, to allow me to play with bridged / routed networking for Virtual Machines.  Except - what about these dnsmasq ports?  Will they be exposed to the outside network?

```
sudo ss -nultp  # List TCP and UDP listening sockets
```

```
Netid    State     Recv-Q    Send-Q                           Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port                                                                                                                 
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                    127.0.0.1:323              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("chronyd",pid=1249,fd=5))                                                                           
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                      0.0.0.0:41662            0.0.0.0:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1216,fd=14))                                                                     
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                      0.0.0.0:5353             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1216,fd=12))                                                                     
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                192.168.122.1:53               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2011,fd=5))                                                                           
udp      UNCONN    0         0                               0.0.0.0%virbr0:67               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2011,fd=3))                                                                           
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                      0.0.0.0:68               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("dhclient",pid=2354,fd=6))                                                                          
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                      0.0.0.0:68               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("dhclient",pid=2184,fd=6))                                                                          
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                        [::1]:323                 [::]:*        users:(("chronyd",pid=1249,fd=6))                                                                           
udp      UNCONN    0         0            [fe80::f3a:8415:60b9:e56b]%wlp2s0:546                 [::]:*        users:(("dhclient",pid=2373,fd=5))                                                                          
udp      UNCONN    0         0             [fe80::7e73:7a0c:e16f:a0d4]%eno1:546                 [::]:*        users:(("dhclient",pid=2242,fd=5))                                                                          
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                         [::]:5353                [::]:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1216,fd=13))                                                                     
udp      UNCONN    0         0                                         [::]:48210               [::]:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=1216,fd=15))                                                                     
tcp      LISTEN    0         32                               192.168.122.1:53               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("dnsmasq",pid=2011,fd=6))                                                                           
tcp      LISTEN    0         5                                    127.0.0.1:631              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=4225,fd=6))                                                                             
tcp      LISTEN    0         5                                        [::1]:631                 [::]:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=4225,fd=5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On 23/11/12 12:50, Gene Czarcinski wrote:](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2012q4/006525.html)

> Libvirt is in the process of changing for using bind-interface to using
>   bind-dynamic to fix a security related issue where dnsmasq was
>   responding to port 53 queries which did not occur on an address on the
>   virtual network interface that instance of dnsmasq was supporting.

From looking at `ps -ax|grep dnsmasq`, it is using the configuration file `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf`.

```
## dnsmasq conf file created by libvirt
strict-order
pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid
except-interface=lo
bind-dynamic
interface=virbr0
#...
```

So they have indeed moved to `bind-dynamic` from `bind-interfaces`.  See also `src/network.c` in dnsmasq:

> In --bind-interfaces, the only access control is the addresses we're listening on. There's nothing to avoid a query to the address of an internal interface arriving via an external interface where we don't want to accept queries, except that in the usual case the addresses of internal interfaces are RFC1918...
>
> The fix is to use --bind-dynamic, which actually checks the arrival interface too.  Tough if your platform doesn't support this.
>
> Note that checking the arrival interface is supported in the standard IPv6 API and always done.

The DHCP socket (port 67) ends up bound to a specific interface.  So we don't need to worry about DHCP, only DNS (port 53).

(dnsmasq only ever uses one DHCP socket.  It listens to all addresses, but when there's exactly one interface it's able to bind to that using `SO_BINDTODEVICE`.  Don't ask me to explain why it only uses one DHCP socket; doing DHCP is generally weird and low-level).

Testing dnsmasq from a second machine:

```
$ ip route add 192.168.124.1 via $FEDORA_IP
$ sudo nmap -A -F 192.168.124.1

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-01-18 16:11 GMT

Nmap scan report for 192.168.124.1
Host is up (0.0023s latency).
Not shown: 98 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE    VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh        OpenSSH 7.1 (protocol 2.0)
|_ssh-hostkey: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
53/tcp open  tcpwrapped
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.11 - 3.14
Network Distance: 1 hop

TRACEROUTE (using port 8888/tcp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.80 ms 192.168.124.1

OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 23.42 seconds
```

So I can see an open TCP port.  However it responds as if it's "tcpwrapped".  That implies if you connect over a different interface from `virbr0`, `dnsmasq` closes the connection without reading any data.  So data you send to it doesn't matter; it can't e.g. exploit a classic buffer overflow.